# Maria DB not starting. Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to install maria db and getting the following issue.

```
[root@localhost ~]# service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

I tried 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' and follows the details.

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status mariadb.service
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2014-09-21 17:19:44 IST; 23s ago
  Process: 2712 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2711 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2683 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2711 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 21 17:19:42 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[2711]: 140921 17:19:42 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err'.
Sep 21 17:19:42 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[2711]: 140921 17:19:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Sep 21 17:19:43 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[2711]: 140921 17:19:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdoma...d ended
Sep 21 17:19:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 21 17:19:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Sep 21 17:19:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.






[root@localhost ~]# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Sun 2014-09-21 02:33:29 IST, end at Sun 2014-09-21 17:20:11 IST. --
Sep 21 17:16:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started dnf makecache.
-- Subject: Unit dnf-makecache.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit dnf-makecache.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 21 17:18:11 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[683]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted
Sep 21 17:19:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
Sep 21 17:19:42 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[2711]: 140921 17:19:42 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err'.
Sep 21 17:19:42 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[2711]: 140921 17:19:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Sep 21 17:19:43 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[2711]: 140921 17:19:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid end
Sep 21 17:19:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 21 17:19:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 21 17:19:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Sep 21 17:20:11 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[683]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted
```

Can any one please help?

I have tried uninstalling and installing many a times but received the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time if the system journal (`journalctl`) doesn't show what the problem was, the MariaDB error log (located in `/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err`) does. Looking into that file you usually see what the problem is.

Most commonly errors that do not disappear after a reinstallation mean that your data directory (by default `/var/lib/mysql/`) is corrupted and the database needs to be reinstalled with [`mysql_install_db`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_install_db/). To make sure you do a clean installation, remove all files located in the data directory and then run `sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the optimal solution for this problem:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

Now we need to look for mysqld service.

```
tcp  0      0 0.0.0.0:3306   0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      32029/mysqld
```

- now kill the process in my case it is (*32029*).
- `kill  32029`

Now use `systemctl start mariadb.service`

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follows:

After installing

```
Run: > mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/

Then: > mysql_secure_installation

And then: systemctl start mariadb
```

with this this, I can resolved.

Answer (score 0):

A quick update for anyone coming here through a Web search.

I had a "failed to start" message following a Debian 9 -> Debian 10 (Buster) in-place server upgrade, and after a bit of digging I found that the following line in /etc/mysql/my.cnf needed updating:

From:

```
[mysqld]
: (other stuff)
:
innodb_large_prefix
```

To:

```
[mysqld]
: (other stuff)
:
innodb_large_prefix = "ON"
```

The clue was the following lines in /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
2020-06-06 16:41:24 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: option '--innodb-large-prefix' requires an argument
2020-06-06 16:41:24 0 [ERROR] Parsing options for plugin 'InnoDB' failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your case, But u can check if mariadb/mysql client is deleted accidentally,
Since in my case, I had deleted the mariadb client repo from shared file,So reinstalled the client as,

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb-dev
```

Note: But before installing client do one thing, for rails app just change the mysql version in gemfile and try to install as `bundle install mysql2`, If its mariadb client issue then it will throw error mentioning that need to install mariadb client or mysql2 client as,

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb-dev
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Please refer other answers in case its not mariadb client issue