# Importerror: libmariadbclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, debian, mariadb, mysql-python

I get this error message, when I want to run my python script on Debian 9.1.
I am using MariaDB 10.1.

What is the problem here? How can I fix it?

My relevant sql code is here :

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ load data local infile 'MYOUTPUTLOCATION' 
into table DEPARTURES
character set latin1
fields terminated by ';'
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines;
"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: That file belongs to the [libmariadbclient18 package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libmariadbclient18/filelist). You shouldn't need to install it manually, if you installed the mariadb client. Does `apt install libmariadbclient18` solve the problem?

Comment: I get this : "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

Comment: And does the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.so.18` exist? In any case, it seems something is wrong with the package. You could try purging and reinstalling (you can run `aptitude why libmariadbclient18` and purge everything that depends on, or recommends it also).

Comment: I tried to remove it with the "sudo apt-get remove --purge" code, and when i reinstall this python-mysqldb i get the same error (because maybe i setted up a wrong version) how can i fix it?

Comment: Assuming you are installing python-mysqldb with apt, you don't have to worry about version, if your apt sources are the original ones. You mean it installs correctly and the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.so.18` doesn't exist?

Comment: but i think it isn't the original, because i changed it, but i don't know how, and how can I install it another way correctrly :\

Comment: Download:1 https://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 python-mysqldb amd64  1.3.7-1.1 and download:2 https://www.ftp.saix.net/DB/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian stretch/main amd64 libmysqlclient18 amd64 10.1.26+maria-l~stretch

Comment: You can use the example they have for stretch here: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Comment: what i have to write? this one? deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

Comment: Remove everything from the sources.list file (and any files you may have in sources.list.d) and replace with the full contents of that example.

Comment: Ahh..i am totally new in linux..can you help me in the command line?

Comment: I can't really help you more than a google search for "edit file linux". You changed the file before, you just have to do the same.

Comment: can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72582208/7516788

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, The python client requires the native libraries. Resolve it by installing `libmariadbclient18` on Debian 9.*.

On Debian 10 (Buster), the package is still available only as `libmariadbclient-dev`.

Comment: Thanks, the buster one worked for me as I was using the Python slim buster Docker image.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error being reported and I found that it was because I was using Python 3 and had installed mysqlconnect via PIP3 to allow connection using the MySQLdb module. This was failing (Python 3 does not support MySQLdb and for some reason mysqlconnect wasn't installing).

I installed PyMySQL via pip3 using...

```
sudo pip3 install PyMySQL
```

... and then in the Python 3 code I changed the module from `MySQLdb` to `pymysql` (import the module on one line and then use it).

Comment: It didn't help in my case