# Error connecting to MariaDB from Linux Environment: ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, mariadb

I am trying to connect to MariaDB using a python connector from a linux machine and while doing so I am getting the following error;

```
(venv) [admin@server connector_testing]$ python mariadb_connector.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mariadb_connector.py", line 15, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(CONNECTION_STRING)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/home/admin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 560, in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/admin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mariadbconnector.py", line 106, in dbapi
    return __import__("mariadb")
  File "/home/admin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mariadb/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._mariadb import (
ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Steps taken to Install mariadb from PYPI:
`pip install sqlalchemy`
`pip install mariadb`

**Note:** *additionally to `pip install mariadb` from PYPI, in a linux systems, the pip script additionally searched for mariadb_config which has to be downloaded and installed from MariaDB website -- [Connector/C]. I have installed Connector/C and was able to successfully install mariadb library from PYPI in the python environment.*

Also, when I was installing MariaDB Connector-C I noticed that in **"lib/mariadb"** directory we have "libmariadb.so.3"

```
mariadb connector-c had these 3 directories:
(venv) [admin@server mariadb-connector-c-3.1.9-centos7-amd64]$ ls -rlt
drwx------. 4 admin admin 38 Jun 19  2020 lib
drwx------. 3 admin admin 21 Jun 19  2020 include
drwx------. 2 admin admin 28 Jun 19  2020 bin

(venv) [admin@server lib]$ ls -lrt
drwx------. 2 admin admin 27 Jun 19  2020 pkgconfig
drwx------. 3 admin admin 90 Jun 19  2020 mariadb

(venv) [admin@server mariadb]$ ls -lrt
-rwx------. 1 admin admin 1525776 Jun 19  2020 libmariadb.so.3
-rw-------. 1 admin admin 2677912 Jun 19  2020 libmariadbclient.a
drwx------. 2 admin admin     186 Jun 19  2020 plugin
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 admin admin      15 Jun 19  2020 libmariadb.so -> libmariadb.so.3
```

So I have copied it to the location where I am getting the error: **/home/admin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mariadb**, but still I am getting the same error.

```
(venv) [admin@server mariadb]$ pwd
/home/admin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mariadb

(venv) [admin@server connector_testing]$ cd /home/admin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mariadb
(venv) [admin@server mariadb]$ ls -lrt
-rwx--x--x. 1 admin admin  465280 Nov 30 14:46 _mariadb.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-rw-------. 1 admin admin     928 Nov 30 14:46 __init__.py
drwx------. 2 admin admin      37 Nov 30 14:46 __pycache__
drwx------. 3 admin admin     119 Nov 30 14:46 constants
-rwx------. 1 admin admin 1525776 Dec  3 10:08 libmariadb.so.3
-rw-------. 1 admin admin 2677912 Dec  3 10:08 libmariadbclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 admin admin      15 Dec  3 10:08 libmariadb.so -> libmariadb.so.3
drwx------. 2 admin admin     186 Dec  3 10:08 plugin
```

If anyone has faced similar issues with mariadb connector, can you please point me in resolving the error.

Thanks in Advance, Nikhil I

Comment: You usually install C libraries by the package manager of your distribution in Linux.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. I do not have access to internet in the linux server, so I have to go with this approach of downloading the tar MariaDB-Connector/C and then try to `pip install mariadb`. Btw, **mariadb** is installed but when I am trying to connect to it using python connector, I am getting this error --> **libmariadb.so.3 not found**

Comment: Hi @KlausD., I *managed to solve the issue by using just another SQL - driver* **(pymysql)** to connect to Maria DB.

Old `CONNECTION_STRING = 'mariadb+mariadbconnector' + '://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(USERNAME, quote(PASSWORD), HOST, str(PORT), DB_NAME)`






Modified to;
New `CONNECTION_STRING = 'mariadb+pymysql' + '://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(USERNAME, quote(PASSWORD), HOST, str(PORT), DB_NAME)`

Thanks

Comment: Can check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72582208/7516788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, MariaDB Connector/Python cannot find the shared library from Connector/C.

If you didn't install Connector/C via package manager (usually package manager takes care of library paths) you have to specify where shared objects can be found.

Solution 1:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/pathof/libmariadbso
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Solution 2 (permanent):

Add the path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig` afterwards (as root)

Comment: This resolved my issue on my ODBC for my asterisk/freepbx install. and yes normally I did not need to set the path, this time I had to. Thank You!

Comment: Additionally to make the change persistent: sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libmaodbc.conf and add this line: /usr/local/lib/mariadb  and once you do that run this again: ldconfig

Comment: How do you find where libmariadb.so.3 is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Just install yum install MariaDB-shared.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I managed to *solve the issue by using just another SQL - driver* **(pymysql)** to connect to Maria DB.

Old:

```
CONNECTION_STRING = 'mariadb+mariadbconnector' + '://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(USERNAME, quote(PASSWORD), HOST, str(PORT), DB_NAME)
```

Modified to:

```
CONNECTION_STRING = 'mariadb+pymysql' + '://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(USERNAME, quote(PASSWORD), HOST, str(PORT), DB_NAME)
```

Thanks

Comment: That is not a solution for your question, it's just a workaround by using another much slower python module.

Comment: Not everybody has access to sudo rights on the server and then this is the only possible solution.