# Langchain is experiencing issues on AWS lambda for database_uri, consistently raising an 'ImportError: libmariadb.so.3' error. for a MySQL database

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-import, importerror, langchain

langchain is not working on AWS , It is always giving "ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" , nowhere i am using mariadb when executing database_uri.

i am using these library and creating aws lambda:

```
openai==0.27.6
urllib3==1.26.15
pandas==2.0.1
slack-sdk==3.21.3
pydantic==2.4.2
langchain==0.0.311
SQLAlchemy==2.0.11
mysqlclient==2.2.0
pymysql==1.1.0

   
rds_host, user_name, password, db_name =retrieve_database_credentials()
database_uri = f"mysql://{user_name}:{password}@{rds_host}/{db_name}"
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(database_uri)
```

Comment: One of the modules that you are importing try to use a mariadb library. You need to figure out which one and how to deploy it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error connecting to MariaDB from Linux Environment: ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258964/error-connecting-to-mariadb-from-linux-environment-importerror-libmariadb-so-3)

Comment: can i write a different logic to generate database_uri which can work for langchain, any help?